# Axon Framework generated proxies prevents Spring AOP proxy generation

Tags: axon

In my use case scenario, I have Aggregates, Sagas and EventHandlers implemented in my service. I also have added Amazon X-Ray which collects data points over methods executions and send these segments to AWS for distributed tracing information.

**My question is: What is the recommended approach to successfully have a working integration between Axon Framework (at a later stage, I'll expand the pointcut to EventHandler, SagaEventHandler, QueryHandler and CommandHandler, etc) and AWS X-Ray, or any other cross-cutting elements that can be achieved using Spring AOP?**

To achieve this support, I've followed standard setup for both Axon and X-Ray. I have the following aggregate:

```
package com.example.domain.company;

import com.example.domain.company.command.RegisterCompany;
import com.example.domain.company.event.CompanyRegistered;
import com.example.domain.company.valueobject.CompanyId;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Company {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    CompanyId companyId;

    @CommandHandler
    public Company(@Valid final RegisterCompany command) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(
            CompanyRegistered.builder()
                .companyId(command.getCompanyId())
                .name(command.getName())
                .build()
        );
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(final CompanyRegistered event) {
        this.companyId = event.getCompanyId();
    }
}
```

And I also have setup X-Ray to create AOP joinpoints:

```
package com.eblock.simulcast.bidding_engine_axon;

import com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.AbstractXRayInterceptor;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class XRayInspector extends AbstractXRayInterceptor {
    @Override
    @Pointcut(
        "@within(com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.XRayEnabled) || " +
        "@target(org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler)" +
        "@target(org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryHandler) || " +
        "@target(org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventHandler)"
    )
    public void xrayEnabledClasses() {}

    @Override    
    protected Map<String, Map<String, Object>> generateMetadata(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Subsegment subsegment) throws Exception {      
        return super.generateMetadata(proceedingJoinPoint, subsegment);    
    }
}
```

What does that mean? It means that every method call existing in a class annotated with `@XRayEnabled`, a new trace sub-segment will be captures and sent to AWS X-Ray, so I can easily drill-down and understand timing spent on specific areas of my code for further optimization.

However, I'm unable to make this setup work, because apparently `@Aggregate` creates a final proxy class, making it impossible to have the aspect applied.

Here is the error I get when I try to bootstrap my service:

```
2020-06-30 16:05:46.681 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:241) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:25) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[service.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[service.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[service.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[service.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:471) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the join point was wrong. Managed to fix that, and it unravelled an issue inside of X-Ray. Dealing with this issue separately of this reported one.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to introduce cross cutting concerns in Axon is to use the interceptors and handler enhancer logic provided.

When it comes to interceptors, I am talking about the `MessageDispatchInterceptor` and `MessageHandlerInterceptor`, with the documentation to be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/messaging-concepts/message-intercepting).

The handler enhancer logic is more likely the way to go if you want to have `Method`/`Executable` level information to be send. The documentation around the topic is somewhat short, but regardless you can find it [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/handler-enhancers).

Subsequently, I figured this is not a new question. This made me look in Axon's [Usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/axonframework), which led me to [the following issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/axonframework/aop%7Csort:date/axonframework/sXD7n2whFyA/t8DNsJudBAAJ) that to some extent reflects your problem with the Aggregate wiring.

That's a bunch of info up there, without giving a direct answer I feel.
To be honest with you? I haven't had the requirement to try this out. But if I were to make this XRay stuff work, I'd have a look at making my own `HandlerEnhancerDefinition` which checks for this specific annotation in combination with `@MessageHandler` annotated methods. It's the `HandlerEnhancerDefinition` which in turn would propagate the required information back.

Another option would be to adjust how Axon wires the Aggregate, although that might be rather complex to achieve. Hence why I'd personally first go for the `HandlerEnhancerDefinition`.

Hope this helps you out Guilherme. Very interested to know whether you'll get this resolved through these suggestions!